# Rails 5.2 import CSV, but check headers text before inserting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need someone to be able to upload a 'sample' file, and then allocate their headers prior to the insert of the file happening.

(Use Case: UserA is uploading a file to be transformed to have alignment with UserB's platform. For this situation, it's just header alignment.)

For instance I am importing a file that has data such as

```
fname, lname
User1, Surname1
User2, Surname2
User3, Surname3
```

I want to import the file, then have them validate where the column belongs.

For instance, in this case it should be mapped to fname:First Name, lname: Last Name

My import task:

```
namespace :csv_tasks do

    require 'csv'    

  task :parse_csv => :environment do
    csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join("lib", "csvs", "test1.csv"))
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => "ISO-8859-1")
    csv.each do |row|
      if row.first
        puts "First row" #Why is this repeating every iteration?
      end
      puts row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

This is elementary, but I'm struggling to see what the next step would be. I thought perhaps putting in `row.first` logic would be my immediate next step, but it seems like due to the `each` `row.first` triggers every time.

Welcome any insight.

Comment: What are you checking with `row.first`, because it seems just doing a "thrutiness" comparison.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I was thinking it would 'just' do something if it was the first row. Essentially just do {X} if the row is the header row.

Comment: At this moment it is just evaluating the code within the if statement beacuse row.first has a value, is truthy. For checking if is the first row, you could use each_with_index, which gives an incremental index for each element within the enumerator, so you can check if at certain point the index is 0 (index.zero?), and do whatever you want. Try `csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts "First row" if index.zero?
  ...
end`.